# Variable scope in nested functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, nested

I have looked through countless examples which indicate that this is supposed to work, but it does not. I was wondering if someone could have a look and indicate why. I am trying to access the variable "dia" from within the setTimeout function, but it always returns undefined:

```
var dialogue = new Array();
dialogue[0] = 'Hi there Mo, I am Mark. I will be guiding through the game for you today';
dialogue[1] = 'Hey there Mark, how you doing?';
dialogue[2] = 'I am doing fine sweetie pie, how about yourself?';
dialogue[3] = 'I am good too, thanks. Are you ready for today, i.e. the big day?';
dialogue[4] = 'I certainly am, Mark';
var dcount;
var loopDelay;
var diatext;
for(dcount = 0; dcount <= dialogue.length; dcount++)   {
    var dia = dialogue[dcount];
    if(dcount == 0) { loopDelay = 0; } else {
        loopDelay = ((dia.length)*1000)/18;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(dia);
        diatext = Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
            .text(dia)
            .textFont({ size: '11px', weight: 'bold' })
            .attr({ x: 200, y: 150, w:400, h:300})
            .css();
    }, loopDelay);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two problems:

The first is that the function you're passing into `setTimeout` has an *enduring reference* to the `dia` variable, **not** a *copy* of `dia`'s value as of when the function was created. So when the functions run, they all see the same value for `dia`, which is the value it has *then*, after the loop is complete.

This example may help make this clearer:

```
var a = 1;
setTimeout(function() {
    alert(a);
}, 0);
a = 2;
setTimeout(function() {
    alert(a);
}, 0);
```

The code above shows us "2" twice. It does not show us "1" and then "2". Both functions access `a` as it is when they *run*.

If you think about it, this is exactly how global variables work. And in fact, there's a reason for that: It's exactly the way global variables work. :-)

More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Now, sometimes, you want to get a copy of `dia`'s value as of when the function was created. In those cases, you usually use a builder function and pass `dia` to it as an argument. The builder function creates a function that closes over the *argument*, rather than `dia`:

```
for(dcount = 0; dcount <= dialogue.length; dcount++)   { // But see note below about <=
    var dia = dialogue[dcount];
    if(dcount == 0) { loopDelay = 0; } else {
        loopDelay = ((dia.length)*1000)/18;
    }
    setTimeout(buildFunction(dia), loopDelay);
}
function buildFunction(d) {
    return function(d) {
        alert(d);
        diatext = Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
            .text(d)
            .textFont({ size: '11px', weight: 'bold' })
            .attr({ x: 200, y: 150, w:400, h:300})
            .css();
    };
}
```

Because the function `buildFunction` returns closes over `d`, which doesn't change, rather than `dia`, which does, it gives us the value as of when it was created.

The second problem is that your loop condition is incorrect, which is why you're seeing `undefined`. Your loop is:

```
for(dcount = 0; dcount <= dialogue.length; dcount++)   {
```

There is no element at `dialogue[dialogue.length]`. The last element is at `dialogue[dialogue.length - 1]`. You should be exiting your loop with `< dialogue.length`, not `<= dialogue.length`. With `< dialogue.length`, you'd still have a problem: `dia` would always be the last entry (see above), but at least it wouldn't be undefined.

Comment: Just to clarify slightly, the reason you see "undefined" when not closing 'dia' as TJ did above is because before the timeout happens your loop finishes, and you are stuck forever accessing dialogue[dialogue.length+1], which is out of bounds.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty: Actually, `dia` doesn't reference `dialogue[dialog.length+1]`, it references `dialogue[dialog.length]`. But that's still out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah, good catch! Looks like I got slightly ahead of myself . What I meant was the loop always ends +1 outside of its bounds by definition, which is dialog.length.

Comment: Note that the return function (on the line 'return function(d) {' does not actually require the parameter 'd' at that point. The closure of buildFunction itself will do the job. 

I would argue additionally that you **should not** fill in this parameter here either. The reason being is that you might be using a pattern that expects that argument to be something else. Perfect example would be addEventListener functions that are passed in as an argument: here, the function can only take in one argument and it is always the caller event type.

Comment: Just simply leaving the return function parameter-less (or, with the appropriate argument expected by the caller) will obviate any associated problems from misunderstanding what is actually required for this builder function pattern to work should someone else who isn't familiar with it tries to decipher its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var dialogue = new Array(); 
dialogue[0] = 'Hi there Mo, I am Mark. I will be guiding through the game for you today';
dialogue[1] = 'Hey there Mark, how you doing?';
dialogue[2] = 'I am doing fine sweetie pie, how about yourself?';
dialogue[3] = 'I am good too, thanks. Are you ready for today, i.e. the big day?';
dialogue[4] = 'I certainly am, Mark';
var dcount;
var loopDelay;
var diatext;
for(dcount = 0; dcount < dialogue.length; dcount++)   {
    var dia = dialogue[dcount];
    if(dcount == 0) { loopDelay = 0; } else {
    loopDelay = ((dia.length)*1000)/18;
}
setTimeout(function(count) {
    alert(dialogue[count]);

}, loopDelay,dcount);
}
```

This solution just pass an argument to the setTimeout function so it can take the array index from there and take the correct item